# Copying Content files on build with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a C# project that has Content files. In MonoDevelop, I can set the type to `Content` and the `Build Action` to `Copy if Newer`. I can do something similar in Visual Studio.

How do I do this with Visual Studio Code? I'm not opening a solution file (I'm opening a directory), and I don't see anything in `tasks.json` or in VSCode that I can use to configure this.

Comment: I would say for VS Code you would need to use Grunt for this sort of thing.

Comment: Code is an editor, so you should open .csproj and edit manually.

Comment: @LexLi the `csproj` already has the content type set (that's how Visual Studio knows to copy it). VSCode doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: @garethb do you have more specific instructions you can post in an answer? This is something regular Visual Studio did automatically, and I expected the C# plugin would also do it.

Comment: @ashes999 if it is already set, use MSBuild to execute the build in tasks.json. The C# extension does not work very well with MSBuild like VS, so manual integration might be a better option.

Comment: Sorry, not for your specific case, but I use grunt to copy move files so though it might be of some use. Maybe this will help you though? https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks

Answer (score 13):

Try to manipulate csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <None Update="FILE_PATH">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>ACTION_TYPE</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

- FILE_PATH is relative path inside your project, ex. "nlog.config".
- ACTION_TYPE - there are two possible choices: **PreserveNewest** (copy if never) and **Always**

Comment: I don't know if there's a difference in build tools, but in VS Code on Linux then I need `<None Include="FILE_PATH">` rather than `Update=...`. Otherwise, I get `The required attribute "Include" is missing from element <None>.`

Comment: Anyone know if there's an extension for vs code to handle this?  It's an extremely common requirement.

Answer (score 10):

Updating the .csproj file with the below line of code helped me

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Include="FolderPath/*">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Should edit the code snippet to put it inside an `<ItemGroup>` tag

Answer (score 2):

This is a direct code if you want to include an appsettings.json in the output directory. This is working on Visual Studio Code (updated version up to the publishing date of this post).

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```