# Getting the path of the file when execute from other project C#

Tags: c#, filepath, xunit

I have created a C# library (bufferutils.cs) that required to get data from a JSON file (in the same directory) and wanted to run a unit test (bufferutilsTest.cs) using xunit. However, I have an issue with the path to get the JSON file.

`bufferutils.cs`

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> getOpcode()
{ 
   var filePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
   var reader = File.ReadAllText(filePath + "/opcodes.json");
   var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>>(reader);

   return values;
}
```

Most of the the path that I get is execution path but **I need the path of the JSON file**

Here is the list that I tried and followed by the path return

1. `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;` => `.../Bitcoin-Lib.Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\opcodes.json`
2. `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);` => `C:\User\UserName\AppData\Roaming\opcodes.json`
3. `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);` => `\.nuget\packages\microsoft.testplatform.testhost\16.5.0\build\netcoreapp2.1\x64\opcodes.json`

Folder structure

```
BitcoinCs-Lib
∟ src
  ∟ Bitcoin-Lib
    ∟ Library
      ∟ opcodes.json
      ∟ bufferutils.cs
  ∟ Bitcoin-Lib.csproj
∟ test
  ∟ Bitcoin-Lib.Test
    ∟ LibraryTests
      ∟ bufferutilsTest.cs
  ∟ Bitcoin-Lib.Test.csproj
```

Comment: In the properties of the JSON file in VisualStudio SolutionExplorer, specify "Copy to output directory"="Copy if newer".

Comment: Is it limited to VisualStudio only? I am using VS code right now. It is a library, so how about the flexibility of the one that you suggested? Whoever need to use this library is required to use the same setting?

Comment: For VS code, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629021/copying-content-files-on-build-with-visual-studio-code/54490612