# How to include extra files when publishing a project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I'm learning c#10 and .net6 and just finished my first project, I'm trying to publish it(create the executable), but I have a folder called "requirements" that contains important files that are needed to ship with the project, but they are just not being included automatically, how can I include this files? Btw I'm using Fedora and Visual Studio Code.
Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083611/vs-code-how-to-copy-files-to-output-directory-depending-on-build-configurations | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629021/copying-content-files-on-build-with-visual-studio-code | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374074/copy-files-to-output-directory-using-csproj-dotnetcore

Answer (score 0):

Editing the "ItemGroup" inside the .csproj file solved the problem.
Example:

```
<None Update="path-to-the-file">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```